# SPARQL INSERT using password

Tags: rdf, sparql, endpoint, virtuoso

I'm currently storing RDF Data into the Virtuoso using HTTP-GET/POST via SPARQL-Endpoint.
But that's kind of a lack of security to always 'GRANT PERMISSION' to 'SPARQL' for INSERT/DELETE graph content and revoking it afterwards.
So, my question: Is there a more secure way to use INSERT or DELETE in a SPARQL query?
I know that using Jena you don't have this issue but I'd like to avoid Java.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's all HTTP you can just put a HTTP "reverse proxy" infront of the SPARQL endpoint, firewall the Update endpoint locally, and just expose the proxy. You can set security policies on the proxy. E.g. Apache or Nginx can be made to work as a reverse proxy easily.

You can find instruction on how to configure password security on the respective websites.

Comment: That's a good point. I think, the easiest way is to set up another SPARQL-Endpoint for the script which e.g. cannot be reached from the web...